# Delete specific characters in text-file php

Tags: php

I have a text like that :

```
 # GEMEL
 Eclipse:        ,frank,jean
 accueil:        ,eclipse,alex
 accueil:        eclipse,truc
```

I want to delete the `,` in front of `frank or eclipse`, it can be any word.

My idea is to check if with have a comma before Eclipse:, or accueil: and if with have one then we delete only the comma to have :

```
 # GEMEL
 Eclipse:        frank,jean
 accueil:        eclipse,alex
 accueil:        eclipse,truc
```

But how can we delete just one commat if she exist ?

I creat the line with :

```
if($fd = file($filename)){

    //1- on recupere les données transmise
    $data = fgets(STDIN);
    $chaine2 = explode(",", $data);
    $chaine = $chaine2[0];
    $user = ",".$chaine2[1]."\n";

    //var_dump($fd);
    foreach ($fd as $key => $value) {
        if(preg_match('/'.$chaine.'/', $value)){
            $fd[$key] = rtrim($value, "\n\r").$user;
        }
    }
    file_put_contents($filename, $fd);
}
```

Comment: After that line: `$fd[$key] = rtrim($value, "\n\r").$user;` use `preg_replace` to remove that comma and update the `$fd[$key]` line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$data = file_get_contents($filename);
$data = preg_replace('/(:\s*),/', '$1', $data);
file_put_contents($filename, $data);
```

The regular expression matches everything from the `:` to the `,`. The parenthesized group matches the part of that before the comma. So we replace it with `$` so that we keep everything except the comma.

Comment: Thx ! you made my day, what is the signification of **$1** why not **''** ?

Comment: **$1** is the first match from subpattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($fd = file($filename)) {
    foreach ($fd as $key => $value) {
        $fd[$key] = preg_replace('/(\s+),/', '$1', $value));
    }
    file_put_contents($filename, $fd);
}
```